# Laravel 5.4 Mix How to Mangle / Uglify / Obfuscate Scripts

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

Laravel 5.4 - Mix How to Mangle / Uglify / Obfuscate Scripts

I use gulp on previous version.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/options.md) documentation:

```
mix.options({
  extractVueStyles: false,
  processCssUrls: true,
  purifyCss: false,
  uglify: {},
  postCss: []
});
```

You can use the uglify option to merge any [custom uglify options](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin) that your project requires

Comment: Hi Paras, where to put the mix options?
I tried this but didn't work:

    mix.js([
        'resources/assets/a.js',
        'resources/assets/b.js'
    ], 'public/js/scripts.js').options({
        uglify: {
            mangle: {
                except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require', 'test_']
            }
        }
    });

   thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @ostrichegret?

Comment: @TJistooshort nope, i haven't found the solution. i will learn webpack

Comment: Seems uglify options are just totally ignored:

mix.options({
    uglify: {
        compress : true,
        comments: false,
        mangle: true
    },
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: []
});

Comment: It looks like that's an option in the compress step.