# Webpack compress the js without console log

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a laravel 5.4 project, where I use **webpack** for managing the js files. I try to set that if I run the `npm run prod` command **compress** my **js files without debug console logs**.

Is it possible?

First I tried with this:

```
mix.options({
    uglify: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: true,
      }
    },
});
```

In `webpack.mix.js`  but it not helped me. (The idea came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42870846/7445344))

Do anyone other has some idea or working setting for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely Uglify is a plugin inside webpack? Not mix?

Comment: I dont know I just gave it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This config should be fine because mix will pass the options directly to `UlifyJsPlugin`.

```
    mix.options({
        uglify: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
          }
        },
    });
```

Check if the plugin is installed by checking your `package.json`..

```
"devDependencies": {
  "laravel-mix": "^0.8.8",
  "uglify-js": "git+https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony",
  // ...
},
```

Comment: Hi! Thx for the answer. I got this error:

".../webpack.mix.js:18
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        ^

ReferenceError: webpack is not defined ...."

`webpack.mix.js` does not really like this plugins config

Comment: Hey @LakiGeri refactored my answer as I admit it was misleading. Your config should be fine but check if you have uglify-js installed in your package.json file. Updated Answer

Comment: @LakiGeri did this help you?

Comment: its working! Thanks for the assistance! Actually I had to add this flag _--optimize-minimize_ to the script: `"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --optimize-minimize --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`.
Thanks again!